# How to guide a new message that holds the current correlation id in an exception flow

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

After the splitter, an exception occurs when processing a message. I want to treat that exception and direct to the common channel a new message with the correlation id of that message that produced the exception and a special header that indicates the error.

I've tried it this way:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow socialMediaErrorFlow() {
     return IntegrationFlows.from("socialMediaErrorChannel")
           .wireTap(sf -> sf.handle("errorService", "handleException"))
           .handle((p, h) -> MessageBuilder.withPayload(p).copyHeaders(h).setHeader("ERROR", true).build())
           .channel("directChannel_2")
           .get();
}
```

**But the aggregator returns this error:**

```
MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.dsl.AggregatorSpec$InternalAggregatingMessageHandler#0]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Null correlation not allowed.  Maybe the CorrelationStrategy is failing?
```

I can not copy the correlation id in the message header.

Does anyone know I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message the arrives to the error channel is `ErrorMessage`. Its `payload` is (typically) `MessagingException`. That one, in turn, has `failedMessage` property.

What you need is something like this:

```
.<MessagingException>handle((p, h) -> MessageBuilder.fromMessage(p.getFailedMessage()).setHeader("ERROR", true).build())
```

You don't need to copy headers because they are already there in the `failedMessage`. The `ErrorMessage` doesn't care (and it can't) about headers because it just deal with the exception.